# CakePHP - Auth component not populating aros table

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I'm following the Auth tutorial and in this stage

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1547/Acts-As-a-Requester

aros table is not populated as stated.
I did not insert records into db directly, I used baked forms as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the code to the app/models/user.php and group.php files as indicated in the example.